# Fetch First record in $key as $value assoc_arr

Tags: php

I have the Assoc_arr and the values in the array is:-

```
Array
(
    [SIZE] => 8.5x11 
    [FOLDING] => HalfFold To 4.25x11 
    [PAPER] => 100lb Gloss Book with Aqueous Coating (C2S) 
    [COLOR] => full/full 
    [TURNAROUND] => Standard 
)
```

When i print this it prints all the values with this code:-

```
    echo "<table>";
  foreach ($final_array as $key => $value)
  {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $key;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $value;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table><br><br>";
```

How can i only fetch the `[SIZE] => 8.5x11` record from the assoc_arr.

Comment: Have you tried this? echo $array['size'];

Comment: @Ayub to be more correct: `echo $final_array['SIZE'];`

Comment: No This Is not the Right Way to Define Assoc_arr. Thanks

Comment: yes whatever the case you have at hand :P ... @TiMESPLiNTER

Comment: @PreeT What do you want now? Define or read the array?

Comment: Yes This will Work. But you have to Define This outer the foreach. Thanks Buddies @TiMESPLiNTER

Comment: You can define outer for each loop just like you did before without any issues, and inside you can put echo $array['SIZE']; and it will work just fine

Answer (score 0):

Check with this:

```
echo "<table>";
foreach ($final_array as $key => $value)
{
    if('SIZE' == $key) {
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo $key;
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $value;
        echo "</td></tr>";
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
}
echo "</table><br><br>";
```

## UPDATE

If you want only the value for `SIZE` key, then no need of any loop. You can get it $final_array['SIZE'], otherwise the above thing will help you.

Comment: @PreeT You should start accepting an answer if it solved your problem. By accepting an answer, you help others as well who sees this post. Also, you give credit to the person who helped you, and you also get reputation in doing so. Higher reputation means unlocking certain site features, and you might get better help from other users as you are more trusting

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo key($arr);
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $arr[key($arr)];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  echo "</table><br><br>";
```

Comment: He want to retrieve first key and value in it.
$key($arr) will return first key of array and hence $arr[key($arr)] will return value in it. It works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code

```
echo "<table>";
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    if('SIZE' == $key) {
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo $key;
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $value;
        echo "</td></tr>";
    }
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`array_keys`](https://www.php.net/array_keys) to get the first key and value:

```
$keys = array_keys($final_array);

$key = $keys[0];
$value = $final_array[$key];
```